# JS/Jquery защита от частых нажиманий

Tags: javascript, jquery, карусель

Предположим есть такой скрипт:

```
$(".event_next").click(function () {          
  $(".test").animate({'margin-left': newValue}, 3000);
}
```

он выполняет анимацию за 3 секунды, нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт повторно не активировался при повторном нажатие на кнопку, пока не завершится текущее выполнение скрипта. А то пользователь может спамить кнопку.

В моём случае, у меня есть карусель которая листает изображения, и при частом нажатие всё работает не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Первое что пришло на ум-- создать флаг, и после выполнения анимации менять его например :

```
var startAnimation = true;
$(".event_next").click(function() {
            if (startAnimation) {
                startAnimation = false;
                $(".test").animate({ 'margin-left': newValue }, 3000, function() {
                    startAnimation = true;
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно блокировать кнопку на время выполнения анимации:

```js
$(".event_next").click(function () {
$(this).attr('disabled', true);
     $(".test").animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 3000);
     setTimeout(function(){$(".event_next").attr('disabled', false);}, 3000);
 });
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="event_next">Нажми меня</button>
<div class="test">
</div>
```